# Framer Motion React App: Slide-In Animation Not Working, Seeking Help to Debug the Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm currently working on a React app with Framer Motion for animations. I'm facing an issue where the slide-in animation is not functioning as expected, while the slide-out animation is working correctly.

**Problem:**

- **Slide-In Animation Issue:**
  The slide-in animation, defined in my Transition.jsx file, doesn't seem to be applied as intended. The background layer (bg-black) should scale in from scaleY: 0 to scaleY: 1, but it remains hidden.
- **Slide-Out Animation:** The slide-out animation, where the background turns red (bg-red-500), works as expected.

**Code:**
transition.jsx:

```
const transition = (OgComponent) => {
  return () => (
    <>
      <motion.div
        className="slide-in fixed top-0 left-0 w-[100%] h-[100vh] bg-black origin-bottom"
        initial={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        animate={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        exit={{ scaleY: 1 }}
        transition={{ duration: 1, ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1] }}
      />
      <OgComponent />
      <motion.div
        className="slide-out fixed top-0 left-0 w-[100%] h-[100vh] bg-red-500 origin-top"
        initial={{ scaleY: 1 }}
        animate={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        exit={{ scaleY: 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 1, ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1] }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default transition;
```

**Additional Details:**

**App.jsx**

```
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />

      <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
        <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
        </Routes>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
}
```

**GIF for the original transition:**
[image]

**Questions:**

- Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Framer Motion slide-in
  animations?
- Are there any potential conflicts in my code or styling that could be
- causing the slide-in animation to not function as expected?

Feel free to share any insights or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Help ..........